# Opening app from browser does not show app icon

Tags: macos, cocoa

When opening app from browser an alert is prompted(image below).I want to know if its possible to add an image to it like on the top left hand side right next to name.If possible than what is the way???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

iconView.image = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:@"/Applications/Skype.app"];

Comment: NSImageView *iconView

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.Check the edit image this is a default pop up that osx shows when opening an app from browser

Comment: What browser do you use? I think this is the browser's bug.

Comment: Do you see an icon??Can you post screenshot??

Comment: I am using firefox